# I have a react application, would like to randomize a <div> elements' occurence on the page base on its x position.

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a react application, would like to randomize a  elements' occurence on the page base on its x position.  Is there a way to do that in REACT jsx?

Heres kind of like what I want to do - this doesnt work.

```
const NavBar = () => (
  <div>
    <section className="rain" 
        {
            left = Math.floor( Math.random() * Number( $divWidth ) ),
            top= Math.floor( Math.random() * Number( $divHeight ) )
        }    >{elements}</section>
  </div>
);
export default NavBar;
```

Basically I want the `<section>` to have a `left and right` property that I can randomize within `REACTS` JSX code boundaries ofcourse.  I tried several ways such as:

```
const elements = [];
const nbDrop = 500;

// function to generate a random number range.
function randRange(minNum, maxNum) {
  return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);
}

for (var i = 1; i < nbDrop; i++) {
  const dropLeft = randRange(0, 1600);
  const dropTop = randRange(-1000, 1400);

  elements.push(<div class="drop" id="drop' + i + '"></div>);
}
const NavBar = () => (
 <div>
    <section className="rain">{elements}</section>
 </div>
);
export default NavBar;
```

This one though up there, I dont know how to insert it on the `jsx` code within the `<span>` element.

Please help.. thanks!

Comment: Did you mean `<section className="rain" left={ Math.floor(Math.random() * Number($divWidth)) } top={ Math.floor(Math.random() * Number($divHeight)) }>`?

Comment: yes.  Thats the goal.  Are you suggesting that?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm suggesting. It's very different from your non-working attempt in your first snippet.

Comment: @Bergi looks like the code you provided allowed me to access the DOM properly as I intended it in my first attempt.  Thanks.